# How do we create a custom share object?

Tags: c#, facebook

**Without knowing the correct name**, how do we create those custom little snippets just like **Spotify** has that not only shows custom links on the bottom but also custom snippets.

[image]

aside from *Like* and *Comment*, there's also a **Share** and **Listen**.

here is one with a simple custom link

[image]

This one has **Giv et gavekort** (give a giftcard) as a new link.

> Where/how can we create such custom links?

---

Just trying things myself, I'm aiming for the `properties` object in the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically looking for [action links](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/), which allow you to specify custom actions to list in the timeline along with the other standard actions on Facebook.

You'll have to go to your application dashboard and configure the action/wording/verbiage that you want to use for your action links.

Once you have all of that, you can post your items to the timeline with your custom actions.

Comment: I would never thought going there, thanks for showing the road :)

Comment: @balexandre I would have put more, but showing how to do it in C# would have been going a bit far and I'm sure there are libraries to help you to it as well, but that's the general concept you're looking for.  Hope it helps.

Comment: it helps a lot, as all I needed was that documentation page, Facebook C# API is a breeze to use when we know what to expect, once again, thanks! :)